# Python incorrectly detects 32-bit system on Windows 8.1 64-bit

Tags: python, windows-7, x86, x86-64, windows-7-x64

```
PS C:\Users\************> C:\Python27\python.exe
Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

Notice the "on win32" part (in "[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32").

"This PC" -> Properties also shows that windows is 64-bit.
Same when I tried installing different Python3 versions.

Why does button detects OS 32-bit incorrectly? This prevents modules that only work on 64-bit from working.

Upd: reading https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/glazier-discuss/Gyrm2IsNhDA - Windows PE might cause problems.

Comment: The architecture flag `win32` is not incorrect. There is no `win64`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`win32` doesn't necessarily mean your windows is a `32bit` system, It means you are on windows operating system, And it is just left there for historical reasons. And the properties on your `This PC` are enough to confirm it is 64bit windows. There is no `win64` btw.

The line you are looking for is this,
`[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]`     - Meaning it was built with MSVC compiler for 64-bit

and to more reliably check for if your interpreter is running as 32bit or 64bit try this,

```
import sys
print(sys.maxsize > 2**32) # must return TRUE for 64bit
```